# How to calculate mean and variance of harmonic mean

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, random-variables

This question is about an application in computer science, specifically it's for the information retrieval system. I'm trying to evaluate the relevance of search results using [mean reciprocal rank (MRR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_reciprocal_rank), however to improve this method, need to somehow normalize MRR. To do the normalization I have to calculate the mean and variance of the follows.

MRR formular:
$$MRR = \frac{1}{|Q|} \sum^{|Q|}\frac{1}{rank_i}$$

Some examples. 
Suppose we have **2 documents and 3 queries**, then we can have MRR:

2 documents could generate `1/2` if the correct suggestion has been put at the 2nd place, `1` if it's been put at the 1st place. There is only one correct answer/suggestion.

- (1 + 1 + 1)/3 = 1
- (1 + 1 + 1/2) / 3 = 5/6
- (1 + 1/2 + 1/2) / 3 = 2/3
- ...

If we have **3 documents and 4 queries**, then MRR could be:

3 documents could generate `1/3` if the correct suggestion has been put at the 3rd place, `1/2` if it's put at the 2nd place, `1` if it's been put at the 1st place.

- (1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3) / 4 = 1/3
- (1 + 1 + 1/2 + 1/2) = 3/4
- (1 + 1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3) = 1/2
- ...

Is there any way to compute the variance and mean of MRR conditional on number of documents, i.e,

VAR(MRR|num_document = 10)

E(MRR| num_document = 10)

given we could have infinity queries ($Q \rightarrow +\infty$), without simulating the permutation (kind of computer science way to solve the problem).

**Update:**

As pointed out in the answer, the underline distribution is not clearly defined. To clarify, here it's assumed to be uniform for the ranks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without specifying a distribution for the rank of the $i^{\rm th}$ query, it is not possible to compute the desired moments.  It is not clear what assumptions are being modeled.  Suppose there are $Q$ queries and $d$ documents.  Then if the system answers a query by randomly guessing a permutation of those $d$ documents, among which there is only one correct answer, the rank of the first correct guess is uniformly distributed on $\{1, 2, \ldots, d\}$.  Thus the reciprocal rank is uniform on $\{1, 1/2, \ldots, 1/d\}$, and the $Q$ queries would be the arithmetic mean of $Q$ such IID random variables.  We need not compute this distribution explicitly (which, although complicated, is tractable), since by linearity of expectation, we have (where I have denoted $\tilde R = \it{MMR}$)
$$\operatorname{E}[\tilde R] = \frac{1}{Q} \sum_{i=1}^Q \operatorname{E}[1/U_i] \overset{\text{iid}}{=} \operatorname{E}[1/U_1] = \sum_{u=1}^d \frac{1}{u} \Pr[U_1 = u] = \frac{H_d}{d},$$ where $U_i \sim \operatorname{DiscreteUniform}(1,d)$ and $H_d = \sum_{u=1}^d 1/u$ is the $d^{\rm th}$ harmonic number.  Due to the IID property of the $U_i$, there is also linearity of variance:  $$\operatorname{Var}[\tilde R] \overset{\text{ind}}{=} \frac{1}{Q^2} \sum_{i=1}^Q \operatorname{Var}[1/U_i] \overset{\text{iid}}{=} \frac{\operatorname{Var}[1/U_1]}{Q}.$$  I leave the remainder of the computation to you as an exercise.

However, as I have stated at the very beginning, the assumed model here is that the system is randomly guessing any permutation on the $d$ documents.  If this is not the case--for example, if the guessing is only limited to $d^* < d$ documents, then $\Pr[\tilde R = 0] > 0$, which is not the case in the above example.  It is also possible to have radically different assumptions about the distribution of $\tilde R$ by saying, for instance, that $\tilde R$ is uniform on all of the unique values it can attain for a fixed $Q$ and $d$, since it is a random variable with discrete and finite support.  But without more information from you as to what assumptions you are wanting to model, it is not possible to be more specific.